# How to auto-animate text highlight in css?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, highlight

I'm trying to create a text highlight animation in css like the one in this gif. From left to right continuously.
[image]

I tried this

```
<p>
The <span class="test">world</span>
</p>


.test {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-size: 0;
    background-position: -100%, 0;
  }

  50% {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 100%, 100%;
  }
}
```

But it's giving some weird glitch effect instead. What am I doing wrong and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use a pseudo element (preferably :after) and play around with the width of that pseudo element.

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
}
.test:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1; /* Place the pseudo element right under the content */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate; /* Make the animation run back and forth */
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }

}
```

```html
<p>
The <span class="test">world</span>
</p>
```

---

References:

[Pseudo elements :after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: Wow cool man. I thought of using the ::before element but didn't get this far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, as I'm reading your answer again, I have a question (I'm new to this). Wouldn't ending the keyframes element at 50% be same as the animation-direction? i.e. it will repeat itself...?

Comment: @Bluebug you can try disabling the animation-direction and check the resulting effect.

Comment: Ah so I was mistaken. Setting the last keyframes at 50% does nothing but speeding it up (2x).  The direction is actually rolling it back.

Comment: Exactly! Try spending some time to learn about the CSS animation properties and play around with different code variations.

Comment: Will do. Thanks mate. ️