# How to apply following properties of transition and animation to the Box

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to apply following properties to the Box.

[image]

But not able to understand how to apply them in the form of transition and animation.

Comment: What does hover state - red mean. Background color, border color, text color….

Answer (score 1):

You need in CSS:

```
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
```

See more about transitions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

The code below is for making an element do something on hover (in this case make the background color red):

```
.myClass:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Also take a look at [this stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197241/how-to-auto-animate-text-highlight-in-css) where they discuss how to manipulate animations.